# jorenvanhocht/laravel-share share only current page

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-blade

I am using the package as https://packagist.org/packages/jorenvanhocht/laravel-share
how can I implement this package to share only current page only

```
  {!! Share::page('https://medmax.com.np/', null, [], '<ul class="ul_social">', '</ul>')
        ->facebook()
        ->twitter()
        ->linkedin()
        ->whatsapp()!!}
```

Comment: read the documenttion https://github.com/jorenvh/laravel-share#sharing-the-current-url

Comment: ```
can we use like this
{!! Share::currentPage('https://medmax.com.np/', null, [], '<ul class="ul_social">', '</ul>')
        ->facebook()
        ->twitter()
        ->linkedin()
        ->whatsapp()!!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the current url
Instead of manually passing an url, you can opt to use the currentPage function.
**Share::currentPage()->facebook();**